# IE11 intermittently not connecting

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-explorer

I'm at work, running Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 in a corporate domain environment. Our IT department isn't too great with intermittent issues, especially if there's a workaround - they'll just tell me to do the workaround.

The problem: sometimes, IE will stop serving up any more pages (clocks for a long time, then gives "This page can't be displayed"), in any tab or window, until I completely exit all browser instances and start fresh (the workaround).
Other times, just one tab, some subset of tabs, or just one window will exhibit this behavior.

In either situation, using CTRL-click to force the link to open in a new tab, opening a whole new browser window, or following a link from some other program, will *sometimes* work, and sometimes not.
For each of these workarounds, once a particular one doesn't work, that workaround continues to not work until I close all IE windows.

In all cases, all other applications can access the network normally - Outlook still gets my mail, other browsers such as Chrome work fine, I can ping websites in CMD, etc.

While I haven't been able to isolate any specific trigger condition, the problem *does* seem to often first surface in a tab that's open to SE. Sometimes, if I notice it and act quickly enough, I can just CTRL-click the link I wanted, close the misbehaving tab, and all is well (sacrificing that tab's back-button history). Rarely, the problem goes away on its own after I switch to some other tab (generally one that's been inactive for a while), with that tab throwing an error like "A problem with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to recover this tab". But most of the time, IE simply becomes completely unusable.

I already have tried clearing my browser cache, and doing an ipconfig release, renew, and flushdns, to no effect. Windows' Network Diagnostic utility doesn't detect any problems with my network connection either, so I'm fairly certain it's an issue with IE itself. And while my RAM utilization is a bit on the high side, it's not so high that I think it could be a factor (for example, it's happening right now and I'm using 2.4 out of 3GB). And closing down programs to reduce my RAM usage doesn't resolve it.

My question is twofold:
What is causing this behavior?
How can I prevent it, and/or is there any way I can resolve it when it happens, *without* closing all IE windows?
(I often have multiple tabs and windows open to help keep track of what I still need to finish after I'm done handling the more urgent thing that interrupted me from it.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. That was quite the read, but you did a great job of explaining the issue. Only have a couple questions; 1) have you run any antivirus and malware scans to ensure there isn't something messing with IE? 2) are you using an add-on that may be causing issues?

Comment: @Charlie, I hadn't thought to run a scan; our corporate security is pretty tight (I don't have admin priveleges on my machine; I can't download a .zip file, let alone an .exe; and all social media sites are blocked by our proxy server), but on your suggestion I ran a scan - it found one cookie, which it deleted. I also learned that the system runs a scan each night.

I likewise don't have the ability to install any browser add-ons, so AFAIK I only have the same ones everyone else in the company has.